# How to make bootstrap widget accordion toggle instead of open and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have looked at a ton of examples and just can't seem to get this right.  I would like this accordion code to toggle, I want to click and open/close each heading individually... since I am calling out to the javascript, is there something I can add to this page to make it work the way I want? Could someone show me what that would be and where I would put it?  Thanks for any help offered!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( function() {
                $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
            } );
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="accordion">
                    <h3>Section 1</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque.</p>
                </div>
                <h3>Section 2</h3>
                <div>
                        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit ame purus.</p>
                </div>
                <h3>Section 3</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.</p>
            </div>
                <h3>Section 4</h3>
                <div>
                        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netuet malesuada.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can class your header, then unbind native accordion click and then rebind with our own event:

```js
$( function() {
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
  })
  var headers = $('#accordion .accordion-header');

  headers.unbind('click').click(function() {
    var panel = $(this).next();
    var isOpen = panel.is(':visible');
 
    panel[isOpen? 'slideUp': 'slideDown']()
        .trigger(isOpen? 'hide': 'show');

    return false;
});

} );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div id="accordion">
                    <h3 class="accordion-header">Section 1</h3>
                    <div>
                        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque.</p>
                </div>
                <h3 class="accordion-header">Section 2</h3>
                <div>
                        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit ame purus.</p>
                </div>
                <h3 class="accordion-header">Section 3</h3>
                <div>
                    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.</p>
            </div>
                <h3 class="accordion-header">Section 4</h3>
                <div>
                        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netuet malesuada.</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

You can see it working at [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xWGjoB?editors=1010).

Comment: That was perfect, just what I needed.  And thank you for the explanation, I learned something!  Appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding some class on your mark up and using `toggleClass` get desire result.

```js
var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
  this.el = el || {};
  this.multiple = multiple || false;

  var links = this.el.find('.article-title');
  links.on('click', {
    el: this.el,
    multiple: this.multiple
  }, this.dropdown)
}

Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
  var $el = e.data.el;
  $this = $(this),
    $next = $this.next();

  $next.slideToggle();
  $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

  if (!e.data.multiple) {
    $el.find('.accordion-content').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
  };
}
var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), true);
```

```css
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="article-title">Section 1</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integerut neque.</p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="article-title">Section 2</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit ame purus.</p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="article-title">Section 3</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.</p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="article-title">Section 4</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netuet malesuada.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I may not have explained correctly.  I want section one to open and stay open until I click on it again.  So, if I open section one and then click on section three, section one should remain open and section three should be open.  Section one won't close again until I click on it....  Is that possible?